# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to AngularJS, I am trying to get JSON data from a file stored in my project location using **`$http get`** of angular but its returning **`cannot read property 'get' of undefined`**.I am injecting $http in my function still its throwing error my code is

```
function eventController($scope, $http) {
    var baseurl = window.location.href;
     var url = baseurl+"Json/data.json";

        $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
            $scope.talks = response;
        });
    }

eventController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Kindly anyone point me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject `$http`, then only you can get `$http` in eventController

```
eventController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
```

Comment: Thanks its worked I will accept your answer once the time limit is over